# To install canon printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I brought a canon pixma G 2000 printer.I can't install it. Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Canon supply their **cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz** from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100839901.html and download and **SAVE** the package

My summary suggestion would be to

1) install the above package; it does not have a ppd file for the G2000 so it likely will not work;

2) knowing that, let's add a ppd file for the G2000;

3) delete any entries in your PRINTER folder that were created by the first run of the install script

4) re-run the install script: any joy?

**Details**

1)go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100839901.html and download and save what will be **cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz**
open a terminal; paste the commands below into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

2) EDIT THE PPD FILE: `sudo gedit /usr/share/ppd/canong3000.ppd`.. see picture below[image]

find the cluster of G3000 entries and change all to G2000; save as

> /usr/share/ppd/canong2000.ppd

and close Gedit

3) delete entries as describe above

4) open your PRINTERS folder; click the ADD button top-left
it should find the G2000; click on till you get to **PROVIDE PPD FILE** as in photo [image]
.. so click the NONE box; look for your name at the top; when the dialogue box opens; click the LEFT arrow; to the left of your name; go the left of the HOME button and click the little icon to its left; that enters your file system and then navigate to go into /usr/share/ppd and find the canong2000.ppd you created; [image]

Comment: dare I suggest that this G2000 needs a different solution to the MP190 or some other Canon device; ... so I would dare to suggest the above question is not a duplicate

Comment: it is not working...

Comment: Anoop: I have edited my first answer; to reflect your feedback: I hope we can get this working for you: ask for more details on how to do stuff if you need it; by the way, I gave you the wrong link first time: my apologies; correct and new link; and new package is now listed above; apologies; that is the one to edit